# Change date format in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

in my lists i have date format `dd/mm/yyyy` is it possible to change this date via regex to like Month date, year (ex: Aug 01, 2015)

Comment: You may have some problem with the `Aug` part

Comment: what is your expected date? Can you put a sample? Did you mean 01/Aug/2015 or 01/08/2015?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you'll need 12 search/replace, one for each month :

- search `(\d{2})/01/(\d{4})`, replace by `Jan \1, \2`
- search `(\d{2})/02/(\d{4})`, replace by `Feb \1, \2`
- ...
- search `(\d{2})/12/(\d{4})`, replace by `Dec \1, \2`