# Change date format via NotePad++

Tags: regex, date, notepad++

I need to change the format of several dates in a file.
This file contains thousand lines.

I wonder if it is possible to convert dates like `Apr 07, 2016` into `2016-04-07` (ISO 8601 international standard) using a regular expression ?

Here are some examples

`Apr 07, 2016` => `2016-04-07`
`Jun 11, 2004` => `2004-06-11`
`Mar 31, 1975` => `1975-03-31`

I'd like to use Notepad++ text editor to do this.

Comment: This is not a job for Npp/regex, you'd better write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: @Toto quite tricky but doable using the dictionary trick.

Comment: You could easily do this in excel instead of writing scripting languages

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew Could you tell me why question is closed as "Too broad" ? Since edit was approved, I thought it was quite clear now ? Thank you ;)

Comment: @stej4n: SO is not a free code writing service. The questions with no described attempts are "gimme-the-code-plz" requests, and shouldn't be answered.

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew Ok. But this question specifically asked for a no-code solution but a tutorial on how to use a text-editor to replace some dates format. Just my opinion, but this request seems interesting to me and is not already answered on another post. Except on this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41111579/change-date-format-in-notepad?rq=1 but it required 12 regex...

Comment: @stej4n: Asked for a tutorial? Then it is definitely an off-topic question.

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew Community made its decision about this post. I won't fight. Thanx btw ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with dictionary trick. (see below)

We'll use the following regular expression :

`(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)(?=[\s\S]*Dictionary.*:\1=(\d+))\s(\d{2}),\s(\d{4})`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1CWFn2/3)

**Using Notepad ++ or Sublime Text**

First, open your file in the text editor and paste this at the bottom of our file:

`Dictionary:Jan=01:Feb=02:Mar=03:Apr=04:May=05:Jun=06:Jul=07:Aug=08:Sep=09:Oct=10:Nov=11:Dec=12`

Then, open *Search/Replace* menu (or use *CTRL+H*) and use :

*Find what:* *our regex*

*Replace with:* `\4-\2-\3`

*Search mode:* Regular expression

Now click *Replace All*

**Demo**

[image: Notepad++]

[image: Sublime Text]

**Explanation**

`(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)` Capture MONTH in the 1st group

`(?=...)` Followed by

`[\s\S]*Dictionary.*` Any character until `Dictionary` word (That's why dictionary must be past at end of the file)

`:\1=(\d+)` After `Dictionary`, match the first capture value followed by `=` then some digits which are captured in the 2nd group, this is the MONTH REPLACEMENT

> Now we can continue to define the date pattern.

`\s(\d{2})` Month is followed by a whitespace and 2 digits which are captured in a 3rd group, this is the DAY

`\s(\d{2}),\s(\d{4})` Day is followed by a comma, a whitespace and 4 digits which are captured in a 4th group, this is the YEAR

> Now all our groups are available, we can build the substitution pattern :

`\4-\2-\3` YEAR-*REPLACEMENT_MONTH*-DAY